# How to solder two 3.7 V LiPo batteries in series and then balance charge them

Tags: charger, lipo, balanced, battery-balance

For a project, I need to power an Arduino Nano 3.3 V BLE. The Nano accepts 5-21 V on its `VIN` pin and then regulates that voltage down to the 3.3 V it needs. To do this, I've got two 3.7 V 1200 mAh LiPo batteries, and I want to connect them in series to create a single 2-cell 7.4v battery. I can then connect this 7.4 V battery to the `VIN` and `GND` pins on the Nano and it will have power. I've already done this and as far as I can tell, it works. Here's a picture of the two cells connected:

[image: Two 3.7 V LiPo cells connected in series]

The problem is that now I need to charge these LiPo batteries. I already have a balance charger (the imax b6 mini from skyrc) so it would be really convenient if I could modify my DIY 2-cell battery to expose the right wires connected to the right places so that I can balance charge both cells in the DIY 7.4 V LiPo at the same time. This has the advantage of making the DIY 2-cell faster to charge, but it will also make less cluttered as I can use the same JST connector for charging the 2-cell as I use for powering the Nano.

I suspect that the balance lead is just a connection to the wire connecting the two 3.7 V cells, but I can't find much online and don't want to play around with things I don't know much about.

This is what the circuit looks like when it's powering the Nano: (Note that I'm using `(+)`and `(-)` respectively to indicate the positive and negative terminals of the cells, `NC` indicates the wire is there, but is not connected)

```
Nano VIN                        Nano GND
    |               NC              |
    |               |               |
    +--(+)LiPo1(-)--+--(+)LiPo2(-)--+
```

This is what I *think* the circuit should look like while balance charging (`BC` is the balance charger):

```
  BC(+)       BC middle lead      BC(-)
    |               |               |
    |               |               |
    +--(+)LiPo1(-)--+--(+)LiPo2(-)--+
```

Am I correct? or am I misunderstanding something?

The other potential issue is that [the LiPo batteries I'm using](https://www.robotics.org.za/DTP503759?search=3.7v) appear to have a small amount of circuitry in the yellow part where the leads connect to the main body of the battery. I don't know if that circuitry is just something simple or if it could cause issues.

Comment: I don't *think* I've soldered directly on to the batteries. Will add pictures to the original post to clarify, but I've just soldered together the leads that come out of the batteries.

Comment: Edit after picture was added to the question: Leads are fine, you're good.

Comment: Thanks! really appreciate the help and comments

Comment: Yes, you're correct about balance charging. The circuitry is probably protecting each cell. I'm not sure if this will interfere with charging but I expect that it wouldn't interfere as long as everything is going well. In case one battery's protection does trip, I'd hope the charger would either trip as well (stop charging) or continue charging the other battery only.